# What determines the final move after triggering Velvet's arm?

Tags: tales-of-berseria

When in combat, pressing R2 triggers her demon arm, and every time it seems to finish with a different move. How do I determine which move is the final arte used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It's dependent on the enemy type you are fighting. All of the characters will do whatever Break Soul is effective against the enemy type. It's automated for your benefit, so knowing the enemy type will let you know what animation will happen.

Comment: Ahh! That explains a lot.